# Українські слова "кавун" та "гарбуз"

Tags: запозичені-слова, іншомовні-слова

Чи хто знає чому в українській мові, слова тюркського походження "кавун" та "гарбуз" мають інше значення ніж в мовах тюркських народів, наприклад у кримських татар:

- *kavun* - диня
- *karpuz* - кавун
- *qabaq* - гарбуз

Answer (score 2):

У китайській, японській та корейській кавун зветься [“西瓜”](https://www.wordsense.eu/%E8%A5%BF%E7%93%9C/) (xi gua: буквально означає західна диня). Але китайський ієрогліф "гуа" дуже гнучкий тому це по суті являє собою абстрактну назву для всіх " динь, кавунів та гарбузів" про останнє ще пізніше напишу.

У японській та корейській це забрали з китайської:

> From Middle Chinese compound 西瓜 (sej kwæ, literally “west + melon”).

Також :

> Турецький карпуз прийшов з грецької ( [karpós καρπός](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%80%CF%8C%CF%82))
> у 1071 році бо вперше з'являється там у арабо-турецькому словнику
> [Dîvânü Lugati't-Türk](https://www.tdk.gov.tr/divanu-lugatit-turk/kasgarli-mahmud-ve-divanu-lugatit-turk/)

Для знаючих турецьку [посилання](https://www.etimolojiturkce.com/kelime/karpuz) на етимологію.

У Китаї кавун був у 10 столітті.

> In the 7th century, watermelons were being cultivated in India, and by
> the 10th century had reached China.

Диня тюркською буде kavun, а саме слово karpuz з'явилось османів з грецької в 11 столітті про що вони пишуть на своїй статті у вікіпедії про [кавун](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karpuz). Тому для нас це до цих пір кавун.

А ще в  Китаї були ще південні дині - гарбузи, ( [南瓜 - дослівно південна диня](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8D%97%E7%93%9C) ).

Окей тоді давайте розбиратись з гарбузом, вийшло що наш гарбуз (який karpuz) отримав назву від кавуна, який у турецькій диня. Почнемо з того, що турки іменують його qabaq та і у багатьох говорах України це залишилось кабаком.

> [КАБА́К](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0#23810) «гарбуз, Cucurbita maxima Duch.» (бот.)

Гарбуз є найновішим овочем у списку тому що потрави у європу з

- Китайська західна диня(то шо кавун) -  kavun( тюрк. диня)
- Китайська південна диня(то що гарбуз) -  karpuz (тюрк. кавун)